# Free jqGrid - JSON encode example using PHP

Tags: php, json, jqgrid

Free jqGrid uses data in the following JSON name:value pairs format:

```
var data = {
        "page": "1",
        "records": "3",
        "rows": [
            { "DataID": "1", "DataDesc": "Test 1", "DataTitle": "Test 1" }
        ]
    };
```

I have the following in the PHP script:

```
$i=0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $data->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row); 
      $i++;
}
print json_encode($data);
```

Which returns:

```
{"rows":[{"cell":[{"user_id":"00082563","first_name":"Peter","case_title":"Male with STI (urethritis)","case_started":"2017-06-02 10:52:10"}]}]}
```

Which looks to be OK.  However, with the JSON parts of the code below, the grid doesn't display at all.

```
    function loadFirstGrid() {
        $("#FirstGrid").jqGrid({
            url: "scripts/json_test.php?user=" + user,
            dataType: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            postData: {
                json: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            colModel: [{
        name: "user_id",
        label: "User ID",
        width: 120
    },
    {
        name: "first_name",
        label: "Name",
        width: 400
    },
    {
        name: "case_title",
        label: "Case Title",
        width: 500
    },
    {
        name: "case_started",
        label: "Case Started",
        width: 200
    },
],
            emtyrecords: "Nothing to display",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortable: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            autowidth: true,
            caption: 'First Grid'
        });
    }
```

But if I remove the postData part to have the following, the grid displays, but of course no data.

```
  function loadFirstGrid() {
    $("#FirstGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "scripts/json_test.php?user=" + user,
        dataType: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colModel: [{...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally worked through this and got it working with this

```
function loadFirstGrid() {
    $("#FirstGrid").jqGrid({
         url: "scripts/json_test.php?user=" + user,
        dataType: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
      colModel: [
            {name: "user_id", label:"User ID", width: 120},
            {name: "first_name", label:"Name", width: 400},
            {name: "case_title", label:"Case Title", width: 500},
            {name: "case_started", label:"Case Started", width: 200},
        ],
        emtyrecords: "Nothing to display",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortable: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autowidth: true,
        caption: 'First Grid',
    });
}
```

To get the correct format JSON for jqGrid:

```
{"page":"1","total":"1","records":"1","rows":[{"user_id":"00082563","first_name":"Peter","case_title":"Male with STI (urethritis)","case_started":"2017-06-02 10:52:10"}]}
```

I used the following PHP script:

```
$page = '1';
$total_pages = '1';
$count = '1';

$data = (object) array('page' => $page, 'total' => $total_pages, 'records' =>$count, 'rows' => "");

  $data->page = $page;
  $data->total = $total_pages;
  $data->records = $count;

$i=0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $data->rows=array($row); 
      $i++;
}
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

(NOTE:  I don't care about the number of pages, total_pages and count as my grids will only ever have one primary record and multiple subgrids with only one record).  So hope this helps someone; there is not much in the documentation or examples that describes how to do this with Free jqGrid ;-(

Comment: The statement "my grids will only ever have one primary record and multiple subgrids with only one record" seems incorrect. If you have only one item in the main grid then only the item can be expanded and thus it could have only one subgrid. Probably you will recreate the grid (with subgrid), but the grid will always have only **one subgrid** if the grid has **only one row**. You should consider which type of grid corresponds better your data. Probably TreeGrid or data grouping more corresponds the data, which you want to display.

Comment: Oleg, my data is based on doctor/patient cases.  So each case is one record for the main grid, with up to three patient consultations per case.  So the main grid has just the one row (e.g. case title, date started etc), then three subgrids for each of the consultations.  See http://130.95.21.121/vmd/evaluation/evaluation_5.php   Select All-Staf from the cohort menu, then select a case in the drop down for the user.  I'm quite happy about how this is turning out.  Plenty of opportunities to refine things...

Comment: 1) I could suggest you to wrap `<table id="case_grid"></table>` to div with small right margin to prevent horizontal scrollbar. For example, `<div style="margin-right:18px"><table id="case_grid"></table></div>`. 2) After displaying main grid you create 3 subgrids with `datatype: "json"` and one makes 3 additional Ajax requests to see the content. I'd recommend you to load all the data at once. For example you use already `"userdata":{"consultations":"3"}`. You can extend it as `"userdata":{"consultations":"3","data1":[...],"data2":[...],"data3":[...]}` and fill subgrids with the data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all JavaScript is case sensitive language and jqGrid will ignore parameter `dataType: "json"`. You should fix it to `datatype: "json"`.

Seconds, you use exotic format of the JSON data:

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "cell": {
            "user_id": "00082563",
            "first_name": "Peter",
            "case_title": "Male with STI (urethritis)",
            "case_started": "2017-06-02 10:52:10"
        }
    }]
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "rows": [ {
        "user_id": "00082563",
        "first_name": "Peter",
        "case_title": "Male with STI (urethritis)",
        "case_started": "2017-06-02 10:52:10"
    }]
}
```

or

```
[ {
    "user_id": "00082563",
    "first_name": "Peter",
    "case_title": "Male with STI (urethritis)",
    "case_started": "2017-06-02 10:52:10"
}]
```

You don't use `loadonce: true` and it's unclear, whether you plan to implement server side paging, sorting and filtering of data or you want to return all the data at once and jqGrid should use *client side* paging, sorting and filtering.

Finally, you should use `name` properties of `colModel` corresponds to the properties of `user_id`. It's very important to understand, that jqGrid have to assign unique `id` to every row of the grid (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)). Thus you have to inform jqGrid, which property contains rowid. You can use either `jsonReader: { id: "user_id" }` or to include property `key: true` in the column `user_id`.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/qgrwymuu/1/ contains an example of described above modifications. It uses Echo service of JSFiddle to simulate server, which responses with some JSON data.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  The major problem was working out how to get the correct JSON format with PHP.  I'm sure this would be useful to many users.  Note that the data is for display purposes only, so I could have used other means of doing this, but I think the grid works quite well for my purposes.

Comment: Also, I haave updated the OP quite a few times, so sorry about that if that has caused confusion.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: You are welcome! I don't use PHP myself, but I'm sure that you will generate JSON data yourself. It's important to use correct `name` properties and rowids. Additionally one should use `{"page":"...","total":"...","records":"...","rows":[...]}` format only if you loads **one page only**, want to implement **server side** paging and want to display really large dataset (>10k).

Comment: OK, what should the JSON format look like if I know I will only have one record/row?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: jqGrid display the data in **the grid** (the table). Thus the input data should contains (or be) array of items, for example, exactly like in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/qgrwymuu/1/ included in my answer. I still find strange that you use such code in the function `loadFirstGrid`. The function could be executed **only once**. The first call will convert the initial empty `<table id="FirstGrid"></table>` to relatively complex structure of divs and tables (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)).

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: The second call of such `loadFirstGrid` will do nothing. Moreover `user` used in URL is not defined in the function. **The initial** value of `user` will be used. To fix the problem you have 2 alternatives: 1) you should create the grid **once** use `url: "scripts/json_test.php", postData: { user: function () { return user; } }`. You should use `$("#FirstGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");` to reload grid with updated `user` value 2) You can include `$("#FirstGrid").jqGrid("GridUnload");` as the first line of `loadFirstGrid`. It will destroy jqGrid if it already exist.